# Como restringir o funcionamento de alguns botões Android

Tags: android, xamarin, shell, sed

Venho tentando alguns dias, algumas alternativas para bloquear os botões de um tablet e depois necessito que eles voltem a funcionar. Vou mostrar algumas maneiras que fiz e qual está operando da melhor forma possível até o momento.

Esta foi a primeira tentativa, porém depois de alguns dias utilizando começou a aparecer erro de permissão para Ler o arquivo dentro da pasta system/usr, sendo que, logo no início ela funcionou normalmente.

```
string sdCard = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            string path = Path.Combine(sdCard, "MyFolder/Generic.kl");

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("/system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl"))
            {

                string line;
                //Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                //the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if ((line.Contains("VOLUME")) || (line.Contains("HOME")) || (line.Contains("POWER")))
                    {
                        line = $"# {line}";
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("HOME"))
                    {
                        line = $"# {line}";
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("SWITCH"))
                    {
                        line = $"# {line}";
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("VOLUME"))
                    {
                        line = $"# {line}";
                    }
                    text += line + "\n";
                }
            }
            Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c rm /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/Generic.kl");

            CreateFile();

            TransferFile();




        void CreateFile()
    {
        string sdCard = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        string path = Path.Combine(sdCard, "backups/gpio-keys.kll");
        // This text is added only once to the file.
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text);
        }
    }





        void TransferFile()
    {
        bool rootaccess = ExecuteAsRootBase.canRunRootCommands();
        //button.Text = rootaccess.ToString();
        if (rootaccess)
        {
            Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c mount -o rw,remount,rw /system");
            Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c rm system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl");
            Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c mv /storage/emulated/0/backups/gpio-keys.kl system/usr/keylayout/");
            Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c chmod 644 /system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl");
            Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c chown system.system /system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl");
        }
    }
```

Como falei anteriormente, esta solução funcionou normalmente durante um período, depois começou a aparecer acesso negado. Para deixar os botões funcionando eu utilizava o seguinte comando, com a mesma lógica:

```
if (line.Contains("HOME"))
{
    line = line.Replace("# ", "");
}
```

Outra solução que adotei que também está sendo muito funcional é esta que segue:

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c sed -i 's/^[^#]*VOLUME_DOWN/# &/' /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su -c sed -i 's/^[^#]*VOLUME_UP/# &/' /system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl");
```

Porém, não consegui ainda tirar o "# " da frente da linha quando a coloco pelo mesmo comando.
Alguém entende de comando sed em adb shell para me ajudar a reescrever a linha da forma que "descomente" esta linha em específico?

Comment: Acredito que eu mesmo tenha encontrado a solução, eu mesmo posso responder minha pergunta?

Comment: Claro que [pode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Acabei não colocando a resposta por não ser uma boa prática. Achas interessante eu remover a pergunta?

Comment: Responder à própria pergunta é uma prática normal e aceite, veja o link que indiquei no comentário anterior. O que interessa à comunidade é ter perguntas com resposta. Já que encontrou a solução, o ideal era você responder.  Responder, apagar ou deixar a pergunta, fica a seu critério.